# WordPress - wp-admin subdomain

Tags: admin

I'm new with WordPress, trying to map the wp-admin to a subdomain:

instead of:
www.mydomain.net/wp-admin
I would like:
admin.mydomain.net

I have already created a sub-domain (I use GoDaddy) that maps admin.mydomain.net to www.mydomain.net/wp-admin

I'm posting this question after searching the whole wide web, but all I found is moving the entire site to a subdomain, which I am not interested in.

Thanks in advance to all the helpers!

Answer (score 4):

The folder location /wp-admin is hardcoded into wordpress in multiple locations. It is pretty problematic to modify the location. WordPress will always go to /wp-admin. There are ways around this, but their are many steps.

You can forward a subdomain to www.mydomain.net/wp-admin but WordPress will still always go through www.mydomain.net/wp-admin.

Here is a reference if you really are interested in doing it...

http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2010-July/thread.html#33458

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response.
I find it hard to believe that I am the only one looking for this implementation.
I'm not trying to rename the wp-admin, just redirect it to a subdomain.
Wouldn't it be possible to do some tweak with .htaccess for the wp-admin folder?
I don't mind doing some code modifications..

Thanks again!